# Empty folder and kernel panic when trying to get SELinux working

Tags: linux, make, selinux

I have very strange things with SELinux.
My post may be will bit disordered, because I'm not completely understand what is going on.

Before all the story, I had good and very stable Linux installation:

```
CentOS 5.5  
uname -a:  
    Linux andreys-comp 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5xen #1 SMP
    Thu Jul 1 19:41:05 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  

getenforce  
echo $? 
0
```

But one day (yesterday) I decided to do `yum update` and in parallel:
`cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@SELinux.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/SELinux -z3 co nsa`
(cvs downloaded all files to /SELinux directory that created itself)

After downloading I read README where it says that for completely install self compiled SELinux I need do:

```
make menuconfig  
make  
make install
```

I did only make (!), but directly after that my computer become crazy.
I don't know whether all this because of system update, or SELinux compilation or both, but Firefox stopped display pages and when I try to run system-config-SELinux that I   recently installed, I get:

```
/usr/lib64/Python2.4/site-packages/SELinux/_SELinux.so: undefined symbol: SELinux_check_securetty_context
```

and not run.
After that I rebooted the system, during system up I get kernel panic and some thing like: "failed to apply SELinux policy" (I don't remember exactly, the message don't stay on screen enough time because computer go down)
So what I did, is to run from LiveCD for disable SELinux in /etc/SELinux/config file, but (!) (here comes culmination moment) when I run ls on / of LiveCD file system, I see:

```
[root@livecd /]# ls -la  
total 180  

drwxr-xr-x   4 root root     0 Aug  9 18:23 SELinux
```

But it is virtual filesystem! I remember that cvs downloaded all source to `/SELinux`.
This is context of this directory: `system_u:object_r:security_t`
More of this, `/SELinux` directory even had files inside of it. One of them was null   character device.
Is this regular directory of LiveCD's file system? Or this is my recently created by `cvs` directory in some mysterious storage and insidiously mounted to root file system of LiveCD?

After that I mounted my hard disk's root file system, I did `ls` and found my SELinux directory that stay there completely competently:

```
[root@livecd VolGroup00-LogVol01]# ls -la  
total 240  

drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Jun  5 07:01 SELinux
```

but (!) this directory now was empty inside! 
This is context of the directory: `system_u:object_r:file_t`

This is mountings that were in LiveCD mode:

```
/dev/mapper/live-rw on / type ext3 (rw,noatime) 
proc on /proc type proc (rw)  
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)  
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)  
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)  
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)  
/dev/hdc on /mnt/live type iso9660 (ro)  
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/disc/sda2 type ext3 (ro)  
/dev/sda6 on /mnt/disc/sda6 type vfat (ro,uid=500)  
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01 on /mnt/lvm/VolGroup00-LogVol01 type ext3 (rw)  
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 on /mnt/lvm/VolGroup00-LogVol00 type ext3 (ro)
```

After all this I disabled SELinux in appropriate file:

```
SELinux=disabled  
SELinuxTYPE=targeted  
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

And I have restarted my computer. After booting up, I do ls on root again and see that again I have SELinux directory, but it again empty!

```
[root@andreys-comp SELinux]# pwd  
/SELinux  
[root@andreys-comp SELinux]# ls  
[root@andreys-comp SELinux]#
```

More of this. When I booted from hard disk, I mounted the `squashfs.img` on LiveCD and `ext3fs.img` on it, that contains all root file system, and this what I see:

```
[root@andreys-comp isotemp2]# mount  

/isotemp/LiveOS/ext3fs.img on /isotemp2 type ext3 (ro,loop=/dev/loop1)  

[root@andreys-comp isotemp2]# ls -l  
total 180  

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Oct  2  2009 SELinux  

[root@andreys-comp isotemp2]# cd SELinux/  
[root@andreys-comp SELinux]# ls  
[root@andreys-comp SELinux]#
```

It is also empty! 
Where all SELinux code?

Now, may be I tell much about SELinux folders, but the question about my general trouble with SELinux is not less important for me.
So, if I enable SELinux I get kernel panic (even if I up in runlevel 1).
After booting with LiveCD and disabling it, all work again.

So I have two questions:

1. Where are all compiled SELinux objects?
2. How I give back harmony and peace to my computer's world?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to boot the live CD, chroot to your disk, mount all the proper mount points (dev ect) and try something like (this may be wrong but I think you get the idea)

```
yum remove selinux
yum install selinux
```

Comment: yum reinstall libselinux if to be exact. So I tried to reinstall it, but it not solved my problem. I simply backuped my configurations, and reinstalled the system.